# Keep the name of the files in the iterations (ArcMap)

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, error-000622

I want to use the iteration tool (ModelBuilder - insert - iterations - raster) and when I use "Zonal Geometry as Table" and write **"t_%Name%** some errors appear, if I use **t_%n%** it works but I need to keep the original name for reference the table

You can see errors here:

[image]

This one is the complete scheme:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly states that its the output name that is the problem, you have .hdf at the end. You need to strip that off to ensure a valid table name.

You can manipulate the %Name% output using the model only Calculate Value tool and a bit of python string slicing to remove hdf from the end.